# For-loop Freezes When Encountering Iterator That Was Ended Early. Is This Normal?

Tags: for-loop, rust, filter, iterator, take

I tried running the below code on `rustc 1.72.0` with `cargo run` :

```
fn main() {
    let ea = (1..).filter(|x| *x < 10).take(10);

    // Initialize a counter
    let mut count = 0;

    println!("Counter has been initialized.");


    // Iterate through the elements and count them
    for _ in ea {
        count += 1;
        println!("Current index: {}", count);
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, the expected behavior should be that the program exits normally after printing 1-9, since `.take()` is supposed to stop early and return all elements if the number of iterator elements is less than `.take()`'s specified parameter (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take).

However, what happened was that my program got frozen with items 1-9 printed out, and I had to press `Ctrl+C` to exit.

[image]

I believe it is also worth noting that `cargo check` found no issues with the code:
[image]

Additionally, creating the iterator with `let ea = (1..10);` instead caused the same program to exit normally after printing values 1-9.

[image]

Is this expected behavior from Rust? If it is, may I know what is causing it, and whether it will be changed in the future?

Comment: 1-9 is only 9 items so the `take` iterates to find the 10th item, which in debug will panic since it ends up wrapping, in release it will wrap and produce `-2147483648` as the 10th item

Comment: @cafce25 are you sure? I added a print statement `println!("Counter has been initialized.");` between the line with the `.take` method and the for loop. If `take` was waiting indefinitely for the 10th item, you wouldn't see 'Counter has been initialized' in the screenshot I provided, and you wouldn't see all the items getting printed out by the for loop, which comes 2 statements after the only line with the `take` method. Per the link to the documentation I provided in my question, `take` is supposed to return an iterator with all the elements within the original iterator in this scenario.

Comment: Well technically you iterating over the iterator returned by `take`  is waiting on the 10th element and ultimately panics and yes [I'm sure](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f5a76480d647d57c95a213c9506bf71). Most iterator adapters including `filter` and `take` are lazy meaning the `.filter(..).take(10)` line does almost no work at all.

Comment: @cafce25, before you edited your earlier statement, you said it was `take` that was waiting indefinitely, not the rest of my program.

Comment: It does still say "`take` iterates" while that is not quite true technically.

Answer (score 2):

It does not freeze, it just overflows. Since the iterator only has 9 elements `< 10`, it counts all the way to `i32::MAX` then overflows back to 0. In debug builds, this will panic. In release builds, it will wrap around and give you 0 ad the tenth element.

Comment: I see... by 'it' you are referring to `take`, yes? If so, this is not expected behavior, as per the documentation for `take` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take),  `take` is supposed to stop early and return all elements if the number of iterator elements is less than `.take()`'s specified parameter.

Comment: @AnonAnon But it is not, it is infinite because of the overflow.

Comment: @AnonAnon the problem is that your input iterator is infinite-ish, so `take` requests the next element (as it's only output 9 so far), and `filter` keeps pulling from the range and discarding everything. [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) documents that it can overflow internally, and will wrap in release mode (panic in debug) when that happens. So `RangeFrom` in release is essentially an infinite iterator.

Comment: @Masklinn, then may I know why `let ea = (1..).filter(|x| *x < 10).take(9);` works just fine with no pause, interruption, or abnormal output?

Comment: Because the first 9 elements of the range are under 10, so `take(9)` yields them, and stops.

Comment: @Masklinn, but by rights, according to documentation (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take), take is 'often used with an infinite iterator, to make it finite'. There should be no problem even if my input iterator is 'infinite-ish' as you said earlier.

Comment: @AnonAnon And it does make it finite, it just takes it a little long to go over all integers, but eventually it'll yield `0` and stop.

Comment: @AnonAnon you have an iterator from 1 to infinity. You then add a filter after it, which only lets numbers, for which the function passed in returns true, go thru. Trying to for-loop over this iterator would print 1 thru 9, then repeat 0 thru 9 indefinitely. Adding a `take(10)` after the filter limits it to 10 elements, but does not in any way prevent it from checking if all numbers between 10 and i32::MAX satisfy the filter closure.

Comment: So I would put more 'blame' for this behaviour on `filter`, not on `take`

Comment: @AnonAnon if you create an infinite iterator of 0, then filter all the elements which are not 1, then `take(10)`, or even just try to get the first element of the iterator for that matter, what do you think happens? Because it's essentially what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different angle than provided by @ChayimFriedman is this:

```rust
// This is an iterator that starts at 1 and increments it by one forever
let it = 1..;

// This iterator is still infinite, but will only yield items that satisfy the filter
let it = it.filter(|x| *x < 10);

// This iterator will yield first 10 elements form the underlying infinite iterator
let it = it.take(10);
```